# how to check if an app is safe

Tags: appsec

There is an app [on Github](https://github.com/soroushamdg/acd)
I was in a rush, so I didn't check, but there is no explanation or source code in its repo.

How could I check if it is not just sniffing my information or something?
Is there any way to ban it to do anything on my system?

Comment: You check for processes that sniff information. That's how you check. If you do not have access to the source code, then you run it in a virus checker, like Virus Total. If you want to know more about what it does, there are malware sandboxes where you can trace its functions. If you are still concerned, then you can run any untrusted apps in an application sandbox.

Comment: You will want to look for the questions here asking about "running untrusted applications" if you want to get detailed advice.